# How do I show dependencies tree in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

My goal is to see the tree of dependencies (such as: appcompat, dagger, etc) in a particular project.

Like the one IntelliJ:

[image]

Answer (score 334, accepted):

The image in the question doesn't really show a tree, just a flat list of everything compiled into the app.

Are you using Gradle?

If so, you can truly see the "tree" by running [a Gradle command](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html)

**Android documentation**: [View the dependency tree](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree)

### GUI

> 1. Select **View** > **Tool Windows** > **Gradle** (or click Gradle icon in the tool windows bar).
> 2. Expand ***AppName*** > **Tasks** > **android** and double-click `androidDependencies`. After Gradle executes the task, the Run window
>    should open to display the output.

### CLI

(produces tree-like list)

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

and/or

(produces flat list)

```
./gradlew app:androidDependencies
```

Where `app` is your module's name

And you get something like so

```
+--- MyApp:mylibrary:unspecified
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
|         |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
|         |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
\--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
     +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
     |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
     |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
     \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
          \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
               \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
```

For specific flavor use the command

```
gradle app:dependencies --configuration <flavorNameRuntimeClasspath>
```

**Note**: If you run `ls` (or `dir` on Windows) in that folder, and don't see `gradlew` (or `gradlew.bat`), you are in the wrong folder.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but I wanted to see from the IDE itself. So that I can browse the dependencies' code.

Comment: You can run that from the IDE, there's a Gradle View on the right side of the IDE along the edge. You said dependency tree, so that's what I assumed you meant. This shows which dependencies are nested within each other and you can identify duplicates

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot in tracking down some transient dependencies.

Comment: I think he meant "browse the dependencies code" like he wrote  ;) Like it's possible in Eclipse (and maybe in IntelliJ IDEA), you can setup a breakpoint inside a dependency framework code. I guess the answer is it's just not possible in Android Studio.

Comment: @Tristan Yes it is. I do it all the time

Comment: It's not what you are showing in this answer though, it's just a non interactive text list of dependencies

Comment: @Tristan a "tree of dependencies" is exactly what is shown. The question did not ask for browsing source **code** of them. The question doesn't say code at all. If you search Maven or Gradle docs for "dependency tree", you get output like this

Comment: The question asked for a dependency tree "Like the one IntelliJ:" with a screen capture. Hard to be more explicit. And then he adds precision saying he wants to "browse the dependencies code". But your answer looks useful to some people anyway, just not the expected answer.

Comment: This may be a newer gradle version thing, but the dependency tree seems to be  displayed with `./gradlew appName:dependencies`. In Android Studio it can be found under `appName > Tasks > help > dependencies`.

Comment: @omahena Yes... Both of those are mentioned in the docs, and my answer. `dependencies` and `androidDependencies` are different, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree with you that the two tasks are different. And I may be holding it wrong... But I could not find a way to display a dependency tree with Gradle 4.6 and the `androidDependencies` task like the one in your answer. The results were just a flat list like the end result of a Gradle dependency search. Any idea why and how to get a tree like in your answer?

Comment: @omahena Well, I copied straight from the documentation. My answer used to say `app:dependencies`

Comment: Also, the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#view-dependency-tree) are outdated.

Comment: @もっくん Again, it used to say that... And the docs used to say it as well, if I recall correctly.. And the bottom of that page does say *Last updated January 23, 2019.*, so...

Comment: Well, something is wrong then, since the output in your answer does not match what we see when running `./gradlew app:androidDependencies`.

Comment: @もっくん I think that output depends on **your** app. I copied what the docs say

Comment: Sorry, but I highly doubt that. If you create a new project with a "Basic Activity" on Android Studio, and you run the `./gradlew app:androidDependencies` task, the tree will be **flat** as oppose to what your answer describes. I understand you copied from the docs, but it won't be the first time they are wrong/outdated.

Comment: chmod +x gradlew on linux if you get permission denied msg

Comment: In Windows do not use `./` . In Mac or Linux it is usually required.

Comment: @TeachMeJava In Windows, use .\ , or use WSL

Comment: @mokkun I am also seeing flat output in AS Bumblebee Patch 2.

Comment: this command is showing all the dependencies in straight line. Not in the heirarchy view

Comment: I have no androidDependencies under Tasks. Only see build and run tasks.

Comment: This answer is 7+ years old. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 32):

On the right side, open the gradle tab > click the gradle icon (execute gradle task), in the popup dialog enter :

```
app:dependencies
```

in the command line field > ok

Comment: This worked for me once I removed `app:` and just executed `dependencies`.  This gives more useful output than the method in norbDEV's answer as it shows a dependency tree.  Possibly the same output as `./gradlew dependencies` but without the requirement of installing a JDK.

Comment: @jk7 `app` is the default module for Android Studio projects. If you have no modules, or want to see dependencies for all modules, yes, `gradle dependencies` also works

Comment: How to find dependencies of a specific flavor?

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan check https://stackoverflow.com/a/63137778/2641657

Comment: Definitely the best and fastest answer !

Answer (score 28):

### Android Studio 3.4

Inspect and visualize each dependency in the dependency graph of your project, as resolved by Gradle during project sync, by following these steps:

1. Android Studio -> File -> **Project Structure** (Dialog)
2. In the left pane of the "Project Structure" window, select **Dependencies**.
3. In the **Modules** pane, select a module for which you’d like to inspect the resolved dependencies.

[image: Project Structure]

4. **For Android Studio 3.6 and above:** On the right side of the "Project Structure" window, look at the **Resolved Dependencies** pane. An example is shown below, where you can click on the Expand arrows to navigate into each sub-dependency. However, it does not allow text searching, like the console output does.

[image: Resolved Dependencies Pane]

[Learn more.](https://d.android.com/studio/releases#psd)

Comment: this is almost what we want. too bad, it neither supports search nor opening/browsing them from here.

Comment: Actually you can also search .. just click somewhere within resolved dependencies and start typing. However I'm facing performance issues

Comment: This helped me get there. But in AS Bumblebee Patch 2, the central pane is flat, not a tree. You have to expand the Target Mdules/Artifacts on the right to see parent dependencies of a selected dependency. There's a possibility that I see different output due to using custom flavors in my build.

Answer (score 22):

### **Android Studio 3.+**

- Open the **Gradle panel**
- Click the **elephant icon**, which has the tooltip "Execute Gradle Task"

[image: Gradle panel screenshot + elephant icon]

- **Select** the *app* gradle project
- In the command line **paste**: `dependencies`
- Click **OK**

[image: Screenshot: Run Gradle Task - Window]

In the **Run panel** you will find the dependency tree.

---

**Another method:**

- Open the **Gradle panel**
- Find the **"(root)"** postfix and open (app's folder name)
- Open the **Tasks** node
- Open the **android** node
- Double click on the **"androidDependencies"**

In the **Run panel** you will find the dependency list

Before a normal build **switch back to the normal Build Configuration** (next to the hammer)

---

### Another useful tool:

**How to find what dependency is updated:** https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

**Usage**

- Add this to project level build.gradle

  ```
  apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"

  buildscript {
    repositories {
      jcenter()    
    }

    dependencies {
      classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.20.0"
    }
  }
  ```
- **Sync Now**
- Open the **Gradle panel**
- Click the **elephant icon**
- **Select** the *root* project
- In the command line **paste**: `dependencyUpdates`
- Click **OK**
- **Wait** a little bit

In the **Run panel** you will find the result.

Comment: This creates a flat list of dependencies rather than a tree, so not as useful if you need to figure out which library is using a particular dependency.  +1 for the "switch back to the normal build configuration" tip.

Answer (score 15):

Finally, I figured it out. What I do is to select **Project** from Project menu (See the image below).

[image]

Comment: This is in no way a dependency _tree_. Dependency trees are used e.g. to find conflicting versions when library A uses library B version 1 while library C uses library B version 2. As the question stands, this answer is not correct. The question should be updated to request a list of used libraries, or cricket_007's answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 14):

In latest android studio canary version you have dependency analyzer in Gradle tool

[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/La3Cp-O05eQ 
This is a video made by JetBrains to introduce this great feature.

Comment: In Android Studio Hedgehog it's in the same location and it opens the _Resolved Dependencies_ view.

Answer (score 7):

terminal command to see all dependencies list is

```
 ./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration implementation
```

Answer (score 7):

> Click the **Gradle** tab and go to ***AppName* > Tasks > help > dependencies**

[image: Android studio dependencies]

Answer (score 4):

Simple use is to type text to Terminal or PowerShell:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Advanced usage:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration implementation
./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration testImplementation
./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration androidTestImplementation
```