# Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonClientException

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

When trying to sign my AKP in Android Studio I keep getting an error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonClientException;
```

I tried to clean my project and other various solutions. I'm afraid of getting into deep directories and messing something up so I was hoping someone could help me!

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.4'

//compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.0'//Removed the 0.2.+
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:2.3.8'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'


compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.3.9'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:1.2.2'
compile 'com.github.rengwuxian:MaterialEditText:2.1.4'

compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'



compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.9.14.jar')
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.4'  // you already have this
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.4.4'





compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'
}
```

Comment: Do you have any jar files in the libs folder related to AWS?

Comment: yes i have 4 of them

Comment: Then that's the problem. Can you not compile those like the others? `compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk....`?

Comment: let me give it a shot

Comment: same issue, updated question

Comment: Other than that, you don't need both Glide and Picasso, and while nineoldandroids is deprecated, you've defined it twice

Comment: Adding those lines does nothing... You've already compiled all jar files in the folder, and your error is saying those overlap

Comment: ill try and remove the unnecessary ones and see if it still works

Comment: Removing them didnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

Remove these jar files from the folder, not just from Gradle

```
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.14.jar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.14.jar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-cognito-2.2.14.jar')
```

Use these dependencies [from Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws) instead

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.4'  // you already have this 
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.4.4'
```

Core is not needed because it's a transitive dependency

Comment: new error: 

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognito/CognitoSyncManager$1;

Comment: Did you actually delete the jar files?

Comment: no i just removed them from the file directory and moved them back

Comment: They need to be completely gone from the libs folder. Also, not sure if you saw my note "you already have that s3 library" defined

Comment: i removed the s3 and congnito .jars from my libs folder, now i get the original error still

Comment: Then there must be another library that's conflicting with the Amazon libraries

Comment: For reference, you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008887/how-do-i-show-dependencies-tree-in-android-studio/39020703#39020703

Comment: I see my external libs but what am i supposed to do?

Comment: I was trying to point out that running `./gradlew app:dependencies`, and see if there are any overlapping aws things, as your error states