# Null pointer on Google Play Services 11.8.0

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I just released a beta with Google Play Services 11.8.0 and started getting this crash on Crashlytics. Anyone else experienced this?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdd)' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInAnonymously(Unknown Source)
```

Edit: As you can tell this isn't a null pointer on my code. It is all inside Google Play Services.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ManjunathaMuniyappa this isn't a generic NullPointerException, it is deep within Google Play Services and the only change I made was update from `11.4.2` to `11.8.0`.

Comment: @casolorz I'm also having the same issue. Have you fixed this?

Comment: No, I'm still on `11.4.2`.

Comment: @casolorz I think that issue is resolved in `15.0.0` version. can you please check?

Comment: Haven't gotten it on my beta users with `15` but I'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.` so I might have to go back to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had some issues with firebase as well. Please check if you have multiple versions of firebase with different version numbers. Check the same for all your other dependencies. You can either do it by command line as described here: 
[Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree)

or if you use Android Studio: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39020547/9093967

If you already checked, please post your gradle files.

Comment: According to Android Studio, all `com.google.firebase` and `com.google.android.gsm` libraries are on `11.8.0`. I'll downgrade back to `11.4.2` until this is solved.

Comment: If you are using FirebaseUI as well, please keep in mind that the Firebase UI and Firebase / Play Services versions have to match according to this table: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android