# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification . Found versions 27.0.2, 25.1.0, 25.0.0 in android studio 2.3

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have one error in gradle file for compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'.

gradle version is 2.3.0

I searched a lot ,but could not solve this problem.
my error is:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.0.2, 25.1.0, 25.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and com.android.support:design:25.1.0

`app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pegah_system.sanduqchehproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
}
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4') {   
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
compile 'com.github.ybq:Endless-RecyclerView:1.0.3'
compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
compile 'com.github.qdxxxx:BezierViewPager:v1.0.5'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Check your dependencies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008887/how-do-i-show-dependencies-tree-in-android-studio/39020703#39020703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because there are conflicted dependencies in your project. You're using some libraries which implicitly using support library `27.0.2`, `25.1.0`, and `25.0.0`.

The following libraries is using a different support library than 27.0.2:

```
compile 'com.github.qdxxxx:BezierViewPager:v1.0.5'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.1.2'
```

BezierViewPager is using support library inside its [build.gradle](https://github.com/qdxxxx/BezierViewPager/blob/master/app/build.gradle):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
```

bottom-bar library is using support library `25.0.2` in its [build.gradle](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/build.gradle) and [library build.gradle](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/bottom-bar/build.gradle):

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 11
    targetSdkVersion = 25
    supportLibraryVersion = "25.3.0"

    junitVersion = "4.12"
}
```

So, you need to exclude the support library from them. You can do it with this:

```
  compile ("com.github.qdxxxx:BezierViewPager:v1.0.5") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'cardview-v7'
  }

  compile ("com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.1.2") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'design'
  }
```

You can check the dependencies tree if you still found the conflicted libraries with:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Comment: I add com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2 ,com.android.support:design:27.0.2 and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2 but  destroy design app! what doing?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what you mean :/

Comment: by exclude support library  and other  library from bottom-bar and BezierViewPager library.design of app  was destroyed.

Comment: You need to add `compile  com.android.support:design:27.0.2`, `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'`, and `compile  com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2`

Comment: excluding means that you want to remove the library. So, you need to add the replacement of the library that you remove.

Comment: Ok yes.tanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your dependencies in dependency tree, you can show it with this command in terminal:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

`app` is your module

There you can find examples mentioned in error message `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2` and `com.android.support:design:25.1.0` and check their versions.

What I usually do when I run into such issues with dependencies is I try to remove them one by one to see where the conflict comes from.