# Gradle Code having Red Line Under the Code and App not Install On Virtual Or Real Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am working on an Android App Until I face a problem that App is not able to install after the successful built and When I open my gradle file It shows a red line under the appcompat Implementation.

I am confused how to resolve It since app I am not able to install app on Real Or Virtual Device.

Here is Dependancies in Gradle code

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'**
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
```

}
[image: Message Under the Line Error]

Comment: the problem you've mentioned has nothing to do with your app install problem

Comment: app not install on mobile after the successful built

Comment: what's the error log ?

Comment: No Error in Logcat

Comment: Log cat is working finely with no error

Comment: I have uploaded Images and I wanna know how to remove the red line from code because I think It prevent the app to install on android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library in your project that uses the library of the android.support library with a different version.

You can use exclude -> [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49348857/8008432)

Read on to better understand [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/android-gradle-and-the-curious-case-of-invisible-dependency-7f1bcc8bb79e).