# How to compile Google Vision API library?

Tags: android, android-library

I am trying to implement Google Vision API, but after adding libraries I am getting the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/anshul/AndroidStudioProjects/CisiveDemo/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/anshul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]))

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.cisive"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev369-1.23.0'
}
```

Dependencies

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
+--- com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0
+--- com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:1.3
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.8.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
+--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0
|    +--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0
|    |    +--- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.23.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.23.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|    |    |    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    |    |         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|    |    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.23.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.23.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.3
|    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
|    \--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0
|         \--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.23.0 (*)
+--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0
|    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.23.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1
+--- com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev369-1.23.0
|    \--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0 (*)
\--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
```

Comment: Remove the jar files from the libs folder?

Comment: `(Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5)` .You need to exclude to duplicate one .

Comment: @ADM please tell me how to do it, I am not able to understand this error

Comment: @cricket_007 there is no jar files in libs folder

Comment: Please show output of this command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008887/how-do-i-show-dependencies-tree-in-android-studio/39020703#39020703

Comment: Try `implementation {('com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev369-1.23.0')
            exclude group:'com.google.guava'
        }`.

Comment: @cricket_007 I got this releaseCompileClasspath after running the command

Comment: What is `'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'`, and why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

These lines are the problem (well, just the first one, but the rest are related).

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev369-1.23.0'
```

If you search in the output of the dependencies, you see the library in the error. `com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0`... Android originally supported JDK6, so even having a JDK5 library is a sign something is wrong.

The [google-api-java-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client) project is in maintenance mode, and is not the recommended library to use for Android development.

Use [Google Play Services APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) instead. (Which you already are using for Auth). For example, there is a Vision API there.

If you need an HTTP Client with Gson support, checkout [Retrofit](https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit)