# Building apk successful but crashes on devices and emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, apk

I am moving a new question from this one [implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094716/implementation-com-android-supportappcompat-v728-0-0)
because I solved my problem thanks to the answers but now my app is continuously crashing.

This is what happens: I build my apk, I send it to the emulator and to my device (galaxy a6+) and I get a "The program has been shut down" (don't know if terms are technically correct, I am translating from Italian) message after installing successfully. On a galaxy s5 the message is "error during data analysis" and never get to install it.

This is my build.gradle after the changes made thanks to the answers on this site :  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1vjmrh196bdy5gn/AADW-DG1YB10s-Csw_UrZtuYa?dl=0

Thank you for any clue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you and am following you from the previous question.

I have found a solution:
First initialize the instance of firebase before using it by adding the line:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

before getting an instance of Firebase.

[image: ScreenShot]

Then in build.gradle change the dependency
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' 
to 
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

It seems that google-services:4.1.0 has an issue