# Android Failed to resolve ExpandableLayout

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shrikanthravi.chatviewlibrary"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.zagum:Android-ExpandIcon:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.2.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.zhihu.android:matisse:0.4.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.lopei:collageview:0.1.3'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':chatview')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1'
}



   //Here is the suggestion when i try to change the version
    All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.0, 27.0.0, 25.3.1. Examples include com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 

    Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).
```

I am trying to import the project which i downloaded from github. After importing the project in android studio i am getting this error also i can't able to run the project.I tried to change the version's to 27.1.0,28.0.0 but the problem is not solved

Comment: try to `clean & build` project first

Comment: I tried already but it is not working

Comment: OK try to add   `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` inside `defaultConfig` in module level `build.gradle` and used latest support lib  `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$28.0.0'`

Comment: [Already posted. Search old answers before asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094716/implementation-com-android-supportappcompat-v728-0-0/53094950#53094950)

Comment: @Er.PratikChatterjee  I tried your suggestion but still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this into your project :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1' // use this
```

because this version is not exist in android try above one version:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' // do not use this
```

**Screenshot:**

http://prntscr.com/n1armz

**EDIT :**

This library is deprecated now that's why you have this issue in your gradle :

```
implementation 'com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.2.0'
```

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1' // use this
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'

Comment: @deepa mention your gradle file.

Comment: @deepa please mention full gradle file

Comment: @deepa edit this : targetSdkVersion

to 

targetSdkVersion 27

Comment: @deepa then clean and rebuild your project I tried your gradle in my project and it works after edit targetSdkVersion 27 into gradle

Comment: i had given targetSdkVersion 27 after that i did clean and rebuild .the problem is not solved

Comment: can you give me that github link which you are using in your lib I will try on my system @deepa

Comment: please try this link

Comment: @deepa I have checked that link and import it and I found this library 'com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.2.0' is now deprecated now
that's why you are getting this error

Comment: k, did you know any alternative dependency for this

Comment: @deepa what do you need in that? CHAT UI?

Comment: yes i need an ui also after fixing the expandable layout issue picasso is not working all the libraries which are used in that project is deprecated now

Comment: @deepa regarding this contact on my mail abhinavguptabit@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.2.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.1.0'
```

when you are using:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Add this to gradle file to avoid google version mismatch warnings,At the end of your build.gradle file

Comment: please tell me where i have to add this line in gradle file

Answer (score 0):

**add implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0' in your gradle**

as an old version of com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 is there imported by some other library which is causing the issue with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0, similarly add the other implementations that occur after this one. so final would be like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
```

... and so on for the l;ibraries having mismatched versions

[implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094716/implementation-com-android-supportappcompat-v728-0-0/53094950#53094950)

**and check for already answered posts before asking new question.**

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.1'

use same 27.0.1 for all the above...version needs to emain same for whichever u user 270.1 or 27.1.0 so make them consistant

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still frustrated

"Engineering is the art of compromise" by Petroski

Since the library is deprecated and you are having Gradle resolution issues.

1. Go to the Repo [here](https://github.com/SilenceDut/ExpandableLayout)
2. Make u download the directory library
3. Go to your Android Project
4. Edit your settings.gradle
5. Add the following line

   include ':app', ':library'
6. then create a folder called "library" in where the "app" folder is
7. copy the content of library folder of the Repo(it contains src, build.gradle etc) to your newly created folder
8. Go to your module level build.gradle then add this line

   implementation project(':library')
9. If issues arise like use "implementation" instead of "compile" or compileSDK is not the same the your project's specs..
10. Go to library/build.gradle just change the "compile" gradle keyword to "implementation"
    and compileSDK should be the sdk you are using....

Phew !! Oboy We Die here!!