# GradleCompatible error: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-support-library

I am beginner to android development. When I build my android project, it is throwing an error

INFO: API 'variantOutput.getPackageLibrary()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getPackageLibrary(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
Affected Modules: capacitor-android

[image]

I tried the solutions suggested in other topic at [implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094716/implementation-com-android-supportappcompat-v728-0-0)

Can anyone help me please? Thank you for your time!

My build.gradle(capacitor-android) file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.1'
    }
}

tasks.withType(Javadoc).all { enabled = false }

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.cordova:framework:7.0.0'
}

def version = System.getenv("BINTRAY_PKG_VERSION")

publish {
    userOrg = 'ionic-team'
    repoName = 'capacitor'
    groupId = 'ionic-team'
    artifactId = 'capacitor-android'
    if (version != null) {
        publishVersion = System.getenv("BINTRAY_PKG_VERSION")
    } else {
        publishVersion = '0.0.0'
    }
    desc = 'Capacitor Android Runtime'
    website = 'https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best of luck with this platform. 
This is not a direct solution, just a small piece of advise. But from now, please do not use the support library. Recently, Google has been introduced [Android JetPack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack). The current stable version of [Android Studio 3.6.1](https://developer.android.com/studio), you will be introduced to AndroidX by default and Google is highly recommended to use it.

**AndroidX - Android Extension Library**: From [AndroidX documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)
You can also migrate from support Android to AndroidX. Just follow this step: `Android Studio > Refactor Menu > Migrate to AndroidX`. It is independent of the Android SDK version.

From [Android Support Revision 28.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions), you can see that this version will be the last feature release under the `android.support` packaging and developers are encouraged to migrate to AndroidX 1.0.0. You may face trouble getting support or a solution if you use the support library. So, it will be wise to use AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'variantOutput.getPackageLibrary()' with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()' in your code. It may works.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation **'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'**

instead of

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation '**com.android.support:appcompat-v4:28.0.0'**

**Option 2:**

Migrate your project to AndroidX

[image]

Comment: Just now, migrated my project to AndroidX. Then on Rebuild, it is throwing new errors. 
 {Project}\node_modules\@capacitor\android\capacitor\src\main\java\com\getcapacitor\Plugin.java:10: error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330816/error-package-android-support-v7-app-does-not-exist

Comment: I tried it and issue resolved. But, it seems, I need to make changes in more files. Now, it is showing problem with support.customtabs. I just replaced               
 //import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsCallback;
import androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsCallback;. And added implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0' in gradle file. Still showing error. Can I close this thread and open new one?

Comment: I am able to fix all of the errors with new AndroidXmappings. Only one issue left it seems. {Project}\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:5:5-9:13: AAPT: error: resource color/colorPrimary  not found.