# ExceptionInInitializerError in Okhttp.Builder w/ sslSocketFactory

Tags: java, android, x509certificate, okhttp

I am working on a project that needs to utilize allow all certificates for a single call and whenever I tried setting the sslSocketFactory, I would receive an error indicating an ExceptionInInitializerError.

I searched SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992760/exceptionininitializererror-in-okhttp-builder-w-multidex-kitkat) question, but it did not resolve the issue for me; same for [this Git issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3336).

My sample code is below:

```
    X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string)
                throws CertificateException {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string)
                throws CertificateException {}
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };
    SSLContext sslContext;
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);
        sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory,
            trustManager).addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
```

Why would I be receiving an error when the params being sent are all valid and not null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue is being caused by a NullPointerException being called deep within the okhttp3 builder method. The exact code is here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at okhttp3.internal.tls.BasicTrustRootIndex.<init>(BasicTrustRootIndex.java:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.buildTrustRootIndex(Platform.java:288)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.buildTrustRootIndex(AndroidPlatform.java:280)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.buildCertificateChainCleaner(Platform.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.buildCertificateChainCleaner(AndroidPlatform.java:230)
        at okhttp3.internal.tls.CertificateChainCleaner.get(CertificateChainCleaner.java:41)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.sslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:694)
```

The cause of this issue is that I had followed a large number of examples on Stackoverflow (IE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032433/2480714)) which tell you to build your x509 TrustManager with that `return null;` line.

The fix was to simply change the one line:

```
    X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string)
                throws CertificateException {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string)
                throws CertificateException {}
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            //Here
            return new X509Certificate[]{};
        }
    };
    .
    .
    .
```

And that resolved the issue.