# Flutter Dependency Audit

Tags: flutter, plugins

So I have this fully created app that uses a few plugins. When the app is compiled in either iOS or Android I would like to audit and list which external libraries belong to which plugin.

I noticed some undesired libraries on my builds (the specific libraries do not matter) but tracking down which plugin is slow and time consuming (looking at platform code, plugin yaml files etc)

Is there a way to list the external dependencies related to each plugin on the console?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command line, please run:

```
flutter pub deps
```

Output:

```
Dart SDK 2.7.0
Flutter SDK 1.12.13+hotfix.5
flutter_news 1.0.0+1
|-- build_runner 1.7.2
|   |-- args...
|   |-- async...
|   |-- build 1.2.2
|   |   |-- analyzer...
|   |   |-- async...
|   |   |-- convert...
|   |   |-- crypto...
|   |   |-- glob...
|   |   |-- logging...
|   |   |-- meta...
|   |   '-- path...
|   |-- build_config 0.4.1+1
|   |   |-- checked_yaml 1.0.2
|   |   |   |-- json_annotation...
|   |   |   |-- source_span...
|   |   |   '-- yaml...
|   |   |-- json_annotation...
|   |   |-- meta...
|   |   |-- path...
|   |   |-- pubspec_parse...
|   |   '-- yaml...
|   |-- build_daemon 2.1.2
|   |   |-- built_collection 4.3.0
|   |   |   |-- collection...
|   |   |   '-- quiver...
|   |   |-- built_value 7.0.0
|   |   |   |-- built_collection...
|   |   |   |-- collection...
|   |   |   |-- fixnum 0.10.11
|   |   |   '-- quiver...
|   |   |-- http_multi_server...
|   |   |-- logging...
...
```

For platform specific audits, you really have to **review each plugin** you're adding (at least for the 3rd party ones).

- Android: [How do I show dependencies tree in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008887/how-do-i-show-dependencies-tree-in-android-studio)
- Android: Look for the plugin's `android/app/build.gradle` file.
- iOS: Look for the plugin's `ios/Podfile`.

More on:

- https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-deps

Do you mind sharing your current `pubspec.yaml` file? So we could further help.

Comment: My problem was that something was loading some old stuff and i got an app store warning about the upcoming UIWebView deprecation; turns out it was that i had not updated firebase plugins.

Comment: My recommendation, especially for those plugins that are not yet on their stable/major version releases, is to read the changelog or docs for possible deprecated APIs. Cheers, Joshua.