# Upgrading Android kotlin version to 1.5.0 throwing error message on build

Tags: android, kotlin

Running with kotlin version '1.4.32' my Android project runs and builds.  Trying to upgrade to kotlin '1.5.0' and my build throws:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDefaultsDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I am not even sure where to start looking.  Anyone else have problems upgrading to kotlin 1.5.0?

Comment: Can you run your command along with --debug ? You might see your errors.

Comment: My solution was degrading the java version to 15, maybe it will help someone

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is due to Dagger's use of older version of `kotlinx-metadata-jvm`.
See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45885

Update your dagger to `2.34`

Comment: Yup, in my case it was Dagger.  Running w/ stacktrace did point to which dependency was causing the issue.  Wish I could accept both answers ;)

Comment: I'm using Dagger 2.35, still getting this error

Comment: @Wackaloon downgrade to 2.34

Comment: I don't even have dagger in my project - only koin - any I get the same error too

Comment: Thanks for this.  been searching for hours.  This worked for me.

Comment: 2.36 was released and it is working. Thanks.

Comment: this solved my problem, but I would like to know that how you found the solution ?

Answer (score 98):

I experienced the same issue today. Ran the gradle build command with `--stacktrace` and got a helpful stacktrace which narrowed down the issue to Moshi library.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not parse metadata! This should only happen if you're using Kotlin <1.1.
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlinpoet.metadata.KotlinPoetMetadata.readKotlinClassMetadata(KotlinPoetMetadata.kt:70)
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlinpoet.metadata.KotlinPoetMetadata.toImmutableKmClass(KotlinPoetMetadata.kt:50)
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.codegen.MoshiCachedClassInspector.toImmutableKmClass(MoshiCachedClassInspector.kt:22)
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.codegen.MetadataKt.targetType(metadata.kt:109)
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.codegen.JsonClassCodegenProcessor.adapterGenerator(JsonClassCodegenProcessor.kt:136)
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.codegen.JsonClassCodegenProcessor.process(JsonClassCodegenProcessor.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:175)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
    ... 41 more
```

Had to update Moshi to `1.12.0` and that did the trick.

Here's a changelog for Moshi `1.12.0` that mentions the fix for 1.5.0: https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-1120

Issue when it was first reported here: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1324

Another issue which mentions the fix here: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1337

So I'd suggest you run gradle build command with `--stacktrace` and figure out which library causes the incompatibility with the `kotlinx-metadata-jvm` library and update it.

Comment: Running with --stacktrace did highlight the package/lib that was causing an issue.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Running with --stacktrace  didn't help, just showed another bunch of internal invocations, still have no idea where it comes from

Comment: For me neither. But it's not that hard to trace, it's one of libraries which uses kapt.

Comment: Thank you! It was `Moshi` for me as well. I was searching for the issue for hours.

Comment: This is it. Moshi is the culprit

Comment: Thank you ! I faced the same problem & this works for me.

Comment: Updating my Moshi with 1.13.0 fixed the issue

Answer (score 18):

In my case dagger caused the issue.
Updating the dependency worked out.

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.37'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.37'
```

Comment: Newer version is `2.40`.

Comment: Get the latest version: https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

Answer (score 18):

This issue resurfaced for me after upgrading my project to Kotlin 1.6.0. In my case it's because of the Moshi JSON serialization lib. They have already included a fix in their next release. In the meantime, I have reverted back to 1.5.31.

https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1433

Comment: They fixed it in 1.13.0

Comment: In my case it was a combo between upgrading room to 2.4.x, kotlin to 1.6.0 on mac M1 chip. Upgrading to Moshi 1.13.0 did the work! Life saver! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue while upgrading Kotlin version to 1.6.10

To fix, I had to update the dagger version to 2.36 or higher and I used 2.40.5

`implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.40.5”`

`kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.40.5"`

To find latest dagger versions - https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

Comment: In our case, AGP 7.1 with Hilt 2.3y.z failed. Bumping hilt to 2.4y.z fixed our issue. Thank youuu

Comment: 2.40.5 worked for me, 2.36 didn't.

Answer (score 13):

If other answers didn't help you, and especially if you're on alpha or beta version of Android Studio, make sure that you using JDK embedded with Android Studio. It was my case, i did use external downloaded JDK.

To change JDK go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle` and select `Embedded JDK` from dropdown `Gradle JDK`.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to kill myself :/

Comment: I was using JDK 11 for new project, but need to change to JDK 1.8 for old project, hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was going to kill myself too. I don't understand why this answer is less vote. Greatest answer.

Answer (score 6):

You should check which of your dependencies probably depends on new kotlin changes in version 1.5.0 and try to update them.
For me the room and dagger was causing problems, i've upgraded it to the latest versions and now i have no problems:

- room to : 2.3.0
- dagger to : 2.35.1

Comment: And Moshi to 1.12.0 and then IDE complains about Kotlin 1.5.0 not being compatible with Compose (In my case)

Comment: this helped me. I got an issue after updating the kotlin version to "1.5.10"
In my case, I updated room version as i am using room in my project

Answer (score 4):

It might not necessarily be dagger or moshi. It can be any library that uses kapt (kotlin annotation processor). Look for kapt in your build.gradle and try to update everything that uses it.

For me it was a library which was using an older version of kotlinpoet.

Answer (score 4):

You should update hilt to `2.42` for kotlin 1.7

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue during build:

> KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction

I had a data binding issue in one of my XML, which threw this error.

This was my case:

abc.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
    </data>
    <TextView
    android:text="@{object.name}"
    ... /> 
</layout>
```

*object* variable was not declared. After declaration, it resolved the build issue.

The error message did not point to the correct location in my case.

Answer (score 1):

yes in my case recently i solved the problem by updating dagger to latest version and gradle update to latest version as well as using latest jdk

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, and finally solved by update moshi to 1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

My dagger error message looked as follows:

> error: [androidprocessor:miscerror]
> dagger.android.processor.androidprocessor was unable to process this
> class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. check for
> compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.

I also had this kapt error: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`

I was given which file dagger was not able to properly process, but no exact information on missing dependency. I applied all the fixes I found in this so. I had to carefully examine all the dependencies I could see in the generated by dagger file for which error was shown.

In my case it was dagger not able to find `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`. I noticed this dependency was upgraded, and due to some fixes I moved to use `androidx.annotation.NonNull` in my code. I actually didnt depend on `org.jetbrains.annotations` - it was being included from some other dependency. The error looked as follows:

> found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0
> (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-16.0.1
> (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1)

I was resolving conflicts which ended up so that dependency was not visible by dagger.

As usual in such cases it was very usefull to see dependecy tree and where dependencies are comming from. Some dependencies were outdated and used `org.jetbrains:annotations` in older version, and I had to either upgrade them or block this dependency from being included in my code with exclude, for example:

```
implementation ("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$rxKotlinVersion") {
  exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
```

for dependency tree listing see here: [How do I show dependencies tree in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008887/how-do-i-show-dependencies-tree-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Got this error due to Gradle not recognizing some of my modules. Re-syncing settings.gradle fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/hilt-android-gradle-plugin to get the latest hilt version.

Then, update the project build.gradle and update to the latest version:

```
dependencies {

    classpath('com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.43.2')

}
```

Do the same for the app build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43.2") 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this error due to Gradle not recognizing . Sync project with gradle file and restarted , it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the dagger graph properly done or not. I missed the @module annotation on top of the class name here:

**Before:**

```
abstract class StorageModule {

}
```

**After:**

```
@module
abstract class StorageModule {

}
```

So, check all the annotations are added or not.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue today when I updated my Kotlin version to **1.9.23**. After updating the hilt and moshi to the latest version it solved the problem.

Moshi version -> **1.15.1**

Hilt dagger version -> **2.51.1**