# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' When I create Moshi Data Class

Tags: android, api, android-studio, retrofit, moshi

When I create Moshi Data Class, It doesn't build properly
The following is the Error when I try to build

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

This is my Data Class using Json to Kotlin Plugin

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class FCMResponse(
    @Json(name = "canonical_ids")
    val canonicalIds: Int = 0,
    @Json(name = "failure")
    val failure: Int = 0,
    @Json(name = "multicast_id")
    val multicastId: Long = 0,
    @Json(name = "results")
    val results: List<Result> = listOf(),
    @Json(name = "success")
    val success: Int = 0
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're using kotlin version 1.5, update dependencies as follow:

- Room to: 2.3.0
- Dagger/Hilt to: 2.35.1
- Moshi to: 1.12.0

[check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410992)