# When created data class with moshi, getting Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

My data class is this code:

```
import android.content.Context
import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Rate(
    @field:Json(name = "name") val code: String,
    @field:Json(name = "value") val value: Float
) {

    fun getName(context: Context): String? {
        return when (code) {
            "AED" -> context.getString(R.string.name_aed)
            "AFN" -> context.getString(R.string.name_afn)
            "ZAR" -> context.getString(R.string.name_zar)
            "ZMW" -> context.getString(R.string.name_zmw)
            "ZWL" -> context.getString(R.string.name_zwl)
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    //apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    //id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt"
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    /*buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }*/
```

...

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.12.0")
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.8.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
}
```

When I delete data class, no errors. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655655/execution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin-when-i-create-moshi-data-class) answer doesn't help as you see. How to solve this? Didn't find solution in any post. I'm not sure what's wrong with code. Have you ever experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Here what worked for me :

First check your Kotlin version (for me worked with Kotlin > 1.6)

Then upgrade your Moshi version to 1.13 but you must add also

```
android.jetifier.ignorelist=moshi-1.13.0
```

to your `gradle.properties` file

Hope it works!