# Dagger-Hilt @AndroidEntryPoint is not working with BottomSheetDialogFragment()

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-hilt, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I am using ViewModel inside BottomSheetDialogFragmet() so I have to mark my BottomSheet with @AndroidEntryPoint.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SearchAddressDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private val viewModel: MyAddressesViewModel by viewModels()
    
    ......
}
```

But when I tried to build my project it is giving me this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing 
org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option 
to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

And here is my output for ***run with --stacktrace***

https://gist.github.com/javlonrahimov/95de968645cace1dfb6e425381f8014b

If I delete the @AndroidEntryPoint above my BottomSheetFragmen() it is building and installing the app. But when I try to open the bottomSheet the app is crashing as I injected my repositories to the ViewModel:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class uz.unical.other.ui.my_addresses.view_model.MyAddressesViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
    at uz.unical.other.ui.my_addresses.dialogs.SearchAddressDialog.getViewModel(SearchAddressDialog.kt:26)
    at uz.unical.other.ui.my_addresses.dialogs.SearchAddressDialog.onResume(SearchAddressDialog.kt:86)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:3039)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.resume(FragmentStateManager.java:607)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:306)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8528)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<uz.unical.other.ui.my_addresses.view_model.MyAddressesViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41) 
    at uz.unical.other.ui.my_addresses.dialogs.SearchAddressDialog.getViewModel(SearchAddressDialog.kt:26) 
    at uz.unical.other.ui.my_addresses.dialogs.SearchAddressDialog.onResume(SearchAddressDialog.kt:86) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:3039) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.resume(FragmentStateManager.java:607) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:306) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8528) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

***@AndroidEntryPoint*** is working without errors on other ordinary Fragments.

UPDATE:

Here is my view model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyAddressesViewModel @Inject constructor(
   private val repository: AddressRepository,
   private val geocoderRepository: GeocoderRepository
) : ViewModel() {}
```

UPDATE 2:
Right now I am annotating BottomSheetDialogFragment() and it is giving me errors while building.

And If I change this

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SearchAddressDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment(){
```

to this

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SearchAddressDialog : Fragment() {
```

it is working perfectly fine.

**Can I actually annotate BottomSheetDialogFragment() with @AndroidEntryPoint?**

UPDATE 3:

[Here is my BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://gist.github.com/javlonrahimov/23a6ba9eb0dc81dbe151bdf93bc74dd3)

Comment: It seems to be right, can you clean build and build again?

Comment: I have tried a clean build. But no success.

Comment: what is your navigation version?

Comment: `const val navigation_version = "2.3.5"`

Comment: have you annotated the view model with: `@HiltViewModel`?

Comment: @MarkKeen Yes I have

Comment: and `@Inject` on the constructor? The error suggests it only knows how to create it using `Class::newInstance` meaning it isn't exposed to dagger as an injectable class.

Comment: Yes, I have annotated with @Inject. I have updated my question to include my ViewModel.

Comment: What version is your kotlin set to? Can you have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410992/upgrading-android-kotlin-version-to-1-5-0-throwing-error-message-on-build

Comment: @AbhishekAN my kotlin version is 1.5.31. I have looked at that question but it didn't help. I have updated my question.

Comment: Have you used underscores in package names anywhere else? Currently your package namespace is : `uz.unical.other.ui.my_addresses.view_model.MyAddressesViewModel` - try renaming the `my_addresses` and `view_model` package names without underscores.

Comment: I have renamed my packages. But it didn't work. Same error.

Comment: Hmm .. Ok. The only thing I'd suggest is creating your own `ViewModelProvider.Factory` manually - adding to your graph in a module and using Dagger through `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)`  in the `BottomSheetDialogFragment()` along with injecting the factory  - basically just Dagger without Hilt.  you have to narrow down where the problem lies with Dagger or Hilt. Standard Dagger does not have a `DaggerBottomSheetDialogFragment` class, so if Hilt does direct mappings through `@AndroidEntryPoint` then it could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long research, I couldn't solve the @AndroidEntryPoint problem.
And I have come up with this: I just pass my ViewModel to my BottomSheetDialogFragment on its constructor:

```
class SearchAddressDialog(
    private val viewModel: MyAddressesViewModel
) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    ........ 
}
```

And I opened my dialog like this:

```
val dialog = SearchAddressDialog(viewModel)
dialog.show(childFragmentManager, SearchAddressDialog.TAG)
```

I have used the ViewModel of the current fragment.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll have to use a `FragmentFactory` if you aren't already, if not try rotating your device (create a configuration change), I'd expect it to throw an error as the FragmentManager won't know how to recreate the Fragment.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented `FragmentFactory` after some crashes :). And now it is working perfectly.

Comment: I find this answer to be the most helpful !

Comment: This answer is not correct. DialogFragments, just like any Fragments, should always have a no-arg empty constructor, and no other constructor. The solution would have been to ensure that the ViewModelProviderFactory is a HiltViewModelProviderFactory.,

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `@Inject` annotation on
`AddressRepository` and `GeocoderRepository` classes constructors? maybe you forget to annotate the constructor of the dependent object of your ViewModel class. because of it Hilt/Dagger is unable to resolve the dependency tree.

If this is the case, annotate all dependent class constructors with `@Inject` the problem will be resolve.

Comment: I have checked all the dependent objects and I think everything is fine. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope you added `hilt-android-gradle-plugin` in your project.

Secondly, there was an issue in dagger-hilt long ago regarding this inheritance dependency but it's already been fixed since 2.28. You can see more details in this link. https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1910

So, for your case without adding `@AndroidEntryPoint` to `BottomSheetDialogFragment` should work but did you also try adding with this? Did it work that way?

Also, can you please share your BottomSheetDialogFragment class?

Comment: Yes, I have the `hilt-android-gradle-plugin` in my project. As for the GitHub issue, It didn't help. I have updated my question to include my BottomSheetDialog.

Comment: From the logcat its doesn't seem like dagger issue.  What is your kotlin version and dagger-hilt version? Also which java version you are using?

Comment: `const val kotlin_version = "1.5.31"`
`const val hilt_version = "2.38.1"`
I am using Java 11

Answer (score 0):

```
@AndroidEntryPoint & @HiltViewModel
```

works perfectly!

Here is my bottom sheet fragment and view model.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class BottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "BottomSheetFragment"
    }

    private val viewModel by viewModels<BottomSheetFragmentViewModel>()
    private var _binding: BottomSheetFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?,): View {
        _binding = BottomSheetFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.test()
    }
}
```

---

```
@HiltViewModel
class BottomSheetFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val localData: LocalRepository,
    private val remoteData: RemoteRepository,
) : BaseViewModel() {

    fun test() {}
}
```

and finally opening it from another fragment like this:

```
BottomSheetFragment().show(childFragmentManager, BottomSheetFragment.TAG);
```

Note: using dagger & hilt version 2.41

Hope this will help!
Happy coding!!