# Media3 ExoPlayer - DefaultTimeBar cannot be cast to TimeBar

Tags: android, kotlin, video, android-jetpack, exoplayer

Im migrating a Video screen from XML to Compose., I need to display Ads with the IMA plugin.

Right now, I'm using this dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.0.0-beta02"
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.0.0-beta02'
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-ima:1.0.0-beta02"
```

And im implementing the player as follows:

```
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer(videoUri: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()
            .apply {
                val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
                val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
                    context,
                    defaultDataSourceFactory
                )
                val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri))

                setMediaSource(source)
                prepare()
            }
    }

    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(factory = {
            PlayerView(context).apply {
                hideController()
                player = exoPlayer
            }
        })
    ) {
        onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
    }
}
```

But, when I run my app and navigate to the ExoPlayer screen, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar cannot be cast to androidx.media3.ui.TimeBar
```

I find this odd, but perhaps in ExoPlayer3 you can customize the TimeBar and choose what class to use. Has someone has faced this before?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your project or one of its dependencies is depending on ExoPlayer 2, which conflicts with AndroidX Media3. You can try viewing the dependency tree to see which ones is depending on it.

About viewing dependency tree, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39008887/4566589).

Comment: Please provide evidence to support your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller_layout_id file linked inside <androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView ... />