# Where's appcompat dependency comes from?

Tags: android

In my Android project `app` module, I have this:
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0`.

And my activity is `class AppActivity : AppCompatActivity()`.

Then I changed my theme to material design by adding `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'`

At this point I'm not sure if I should delete `appcompat`, I think I can't because `AppCompatActivity` comes from it. As I want to prove it, so I deleted `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0`, after sync all goes well.

Also I can check the `AppCompatActivity` is from `appcompat:1.5.0`(sorry for the image is not that clear)

[image]

So my question is where is it from as I have deleted it?

To find if it's from any other libraries, I tried add it back but upgrade it to 1.6.1:
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'`

Then If it's using from any other libraries it should be still 1.5.0.

But I got:

[image]

Anyway to know about it? Thanks!

**EDIT**

As the accepted answer described, use `Project structures` -> `Dependencies`.

At the first I tried this too but didn't find out my answer, here I expand a bit more. e.g.

I selected: `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0`
Then on the right side `Target Module/Artifacts` it shows your module you want to check where's it from. Here is my project image:

[image]

Then I know it's from `material:1.8.0` I can delete `appcompat` anyway. It's not from 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Check [dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008887/how-do-i-show-dependencies-tree-in-android-studio). u can also exclude/force the version .

Comment: There might be situations where you'd want to declare a dependency explicitly, rather than depend on it via another dependency (aka transitive dependency). You can use https://github.com/autonomousapps/dependency-analysis-android-gradle-plugin to check for transitive dependencies, among other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using AndroidStudio, check this way.
Go to `project structure` -> `Dependencies` -> `<All Modules>`
scroll `AppCompat` library and click the undesired version, this should show you the detail dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you implement two appcompat lib in your gradle file, or just gradle's cache. Here is a easy way to find out:

1. First  : Into the lib your depend on
2. Second : Click this button in your Android Studio
   [image]
3. You will see left of screen just like this
   [image]
   After this , you will find out with lib depended

Ops, I have two constaintlayout depend in my project
[image]
So, just need delete one of them in my gradle file

Comment: I deleted gradle caches. And checked `External libraries`, it's only 1.5.0 version there. In gradle there's no appcompact. Still not sure where is it from.

Comment: If your project depend on some third party lib, maybe that part contains appcompat libs

Comment: So should delete 3rd party libraries and check one by one?