# Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy: Invalid Data safety form

Tags: android, google-play-services

Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy: Invalid Data safety form.

We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.
We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.
You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

**How to fix**
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass: Consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of the SDK if available from your SDK provider, or removing the SDK.

[image]

***`I've Updated all the playstore dependencies.`***

Comment: Your data safety information and privacy policy aren't accurate for those libraries-  they violate what you claim.  Remove those libraries entirely, or fix your data safety and privacy policy to include what those libraries actually do.

Comment: @GabeSechan , I have updated all the libraries. I still have not found these types of libraries.

Comment: Have you [gone through each of your libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39008887/295004) to see who might be using it?